# acts_as_taggable runs queries on every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

I have a `User.rb` model that includes the line:

```
acts_as_taggable_on :industries, :uxes
```

[The 'uxes' term contains UX preferences belonging to the user, such as whether they dismissed a certain help box.]

What I've noticed is the following queries are loading at the top of every request involving a `@user`:

```
User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 354 LIMIT 1
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.id = `taggings`.tag_id WHERE ((`taggings`.taggable_id = 354) AND (`taggings`.taggable_type = 'User')) AND (taggings.context = 'uxes' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  
AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2012-09-17 09:44:24', `perishable_token` = 'un5eK7SHDNzTegt7GPUk', `updated_at` = '2012-09-17 09:44:24' WHERE `users`.`id` = 354
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.id = `taggings`.tag_id WHERE ((`taggings`.taggable_id = 354) AND (`taggings`.taggable_type = 'User')) AND (taggings.context = 'uxes' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `taggings`.* FROM `taggings` WHERE `taggings`.`tagger_type` IS NULL AND `taggings`.`tagger_id` IS NULL AND `taggings`.`context` = 'uxes' AND `taggings`.`tag_id` IN (NULL) AND (`taggings`.taggable_id = 354 AND `taggings`.taggable_type = 'User')
```

These queries are adding time to every pageload on which a user is loaded (i.e. 90%+ of all pageloads). Why is `acts_as_taggable` forcing these queries to occur, and how can I stop it from loading them unless necessary?

Answer (score 2):

The  `ActsAsTaggableOn` gem allegedly supports [caching your tag lists](https://makandracards.com/makandra/3203-actsastaggableon-cache-tag-lists) directly 
in your model, see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946783/how-to-cache-tags-with-acts-as-taggable-on). To enable caching for tag lists, simply add a `cached_tag_list` column to your table, because the caching methods look for a column called “cached_#{context}_list” 
on the [acts_as_taggable](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/acts_as_taggable_on/) record table. Not sure if this works, though.