# Acts-as-taggable-on caching does not seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

I'm using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem v.2.4.1 with rails v.3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3p392. 
I've just upgraded the gem from v.2.2.1 to v.2.4.1 and following [these instructions](https://makandracards.com/makandra/3203-actsastaggableon-cache-tag-lists) I've added a 'cached_tag_list' column to my database. The column seems to update as expected when a record is saved/updated but when I try to fetch tagged records I can still see SQL tag queries being performed (and not fetching cached tags). 
This is my code in my view:

```
<% if !tape.tag_list.empty? %>
    <% for tag in tape.tags %>
        <span><%= tag.name %></span>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My model has the following line:

```
acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```

And here's a screenshot from newrelic showing the SQL queries being performed even though these records have saved tag strings in the ''cached_tag_list' database column.
[image: SQL queries performed, caching not working]

Any ideas how to enable caching with this gem?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946783/how-to-cache-tags-with-acts-as-taggable-on</a>

Comment: @David I don't think the linked answer is relevant in my case:

1) My migration code posted above is the same with the answer in the link you provide and run fine so this is not the problem (actually I used code from this question).
2) I'm not using owned tags so this is not the problem either.

Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Until this bug is fixed, here's a workaround I've implemented:

```
    <% if tape.cached_tag_list != "" %>
        <% for tag in tape.cached_tag_list.split(', ') %>
            <span><%= tag %></span>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Since the cached_tag_list column is updated properly every time a record is saved I'm using it to get each record's tags without calling extra SQL queries, just one. Since the cached_tag_list column stores a string with comma-seperated tags I'm using split() function to get each one of them.

I'm sharing this in case this is useful to anyone else..

Comment: is `cached_tag_list` a column in the parent table? or is it purely a method?